# pytest parametrize an autouse fixture

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a large amount of tests (high 100s) that use pytest and rely on a fixture that is set for autouse. I need to run those same 100s of tests with a slight variation that's controlled by the fixture.

Consider the following setup that demonstrates the technique I am trying to use, and does not work:

In `conftest.py`

```
import pytest

def patch_0() -> int:
   return 0

def patch_1() -> int:
   return 1

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("patch", [patch_0, patch_1])
def patch_time_per_test(monkeypatch, patch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("time.time", patch)
```

In `my_test.py`

```
import time
  
def test_00():
    assert time.time() < 100
```

Here's a sample of the error I'm seeing:

```
file ../conftest.py, line 14
  @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
  @pytest.mark.parametrize("patch", [patch_0, patch_1])
  def patch_time_per_test(monkeypatch, patch):
E       fixture 'patch' not found
```

I see a number of [somewhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999470/parametrize-pytest-fixture) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228895/how-to-parametrize-a-pytest-fixture), but I can't seem to find how to parametrize a fixture when `autouse=True`.  It seems like to do what I'm trying to do I need to update 100s of tests with the `@pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator and parametrize each of them independently. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out myself.  It's as simple as this:

In `conftest.py`

```
import pytest

def patch_0() -> int:
   return 0

def patch_1() -> int:
   return 1

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, params=[patch_0, patch_1])
def patch_time_per_test(monkeypatch, request): 
    monkeypatch.setattr("time.time", request.param)
```